# Converting string to bytes and writing to file in Lua

Tags: string, lua, byte

I'm trying to convert and write string data into the file as bytes.

I have already tried something to, but instead of seeing 00 inside hexdump, im seeing 0x30 inside file which is hexadecimal value for character 0.

Here is what I wrote:

```
local data = "000000010000000100000004000000080000000100000000"
for i=1,#data,2 do
  file:write(tonumber(data:sub(i,i+1)))
end
io.close(file)
```

When I do hexdump of the file I'm getting this:

```
0000000 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 34 30 30 30 38  
0000010 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30  
0000018
```

Expected is:

```
0000000 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 08  
0000010 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00  
0000018
```

Comment: Use `file:close()` for consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Use [string.char](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.char) to convert numbers to bytes:

```
file:write(string.char(tonumber(data:sub(i,i+1))))
```

If the strings contains hexadecimal, use `tonumber(...,16)`.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`string.char`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.char) in one way:

```
local data = "000000010000000100000004000000080000000100000000"
for i=1,#data,2 do
  file:write(string.char(tonumber(data:sub(i,i+1), 16)))
end
io.close(file)
```

or another:

```
local data = string.char(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
file:write(data)
io.close(file)
```

Note that strings in Lua may contain any bytes you want including null bytes. See [Values and Types](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1).